# Make use of variable from while read loop

Tags: bash, variables

In my bash script I use `while read` loop and a helper function `fv()`:

```
fv() {
    case "$1" in
    out) echo $VAR
    ;;
    *  ) VAR="$VAR $1"
    ;; 
    esac
}

cat "$1" | while read line
    do
        ...some processings...
        fv some-str-value
    done

echo "`fv out`"
```

in a hope that I can distil value from `while read` loop in a variable accessible in rest of the script.
But above snippet is no good, as I get no output.

Is there easy way to solve this - output string from this loop in a variable that would be accessible in rest of the script - without reformatting my script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your while loop by `while read line ; do ... ; done < $1`:

```
#!/bin/bash

function fv
{
    case "$1" in
    out) echo $VAR
    ;;
    *  ) VAR="$VAR $1"
    ;; 
    esac
}

while read line
    do
        fv "$line\n"
    done < "$1"

echo "$(fv out)"
```

Answer (score 5):

As no one has explained to you *why* your code didn't work, I will.

When you use `cat "$1" |`, you are making that loop execute in a subshell. The `VAR` variable used in that subshell starts as a copy of `VAR` from the main script, and any changes to it are limited to that copy (the subshell's scope), they don't affect the script's original `VAR`. By removing the [useless use of cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat), you remove the pipeline and so the loop is executed in the main shell, so it can (and does) alter the correct copy of `VAR`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. First I was surprised as why my variables inside this loop are reset. I found out, here on SO, that it's because of subshell execution. Then I thought to create this helper function and create variables there instead in a loop, from which I will only output values, as obvious from my posted snippet. What it's still not clear to me is why this outside function `fv()`, where I create the variable, is influenced by this subsheel loop, but I imagine it's drowned in subshell as it's called from there.

Comment: Functions are executed within the current shell, not a subshell.  That means that not only can they see the environment at the point where they are called, they can alter it there.

Answer (score 1):

Stop piping to read.

```
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to Linux and can't decrypt your message. Can you expand it a bit?